# About the inscribed sphere and the exspheres of a $n$-dimensional simplex

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Let us consider $n$-dimensional simplex $K$ in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space. Let $r_0$ be the radius of the inscribed sphere of $K$, and let be $r_1, r_2, \cdots, r_{n+1}$ be each radius of the [exsphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exsphere_%28polyhedra%29) of $K$.

Then, here is my question.

> **Question** : How can we represent $r_0$ by $r_1, r_2, \cdots, r_{n+1}$?

**Remark** : This question has been [asked previously on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535692/about-the-inscribed-sphere-and-the-escribed-spheres-of-a-n-dimensional-simplex) without receiving any answers.

**Motivation** : I've known the followings :

In the $n=2$ case, 
$$r_0=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{r_1}+\frac{1}{r_2}+\frac{1}{r_3}}.$$
In the $n=3$ case, 
$$r_0=\frac{2}{\frac{1}{r_1}+\frac{1}{r_2}+\frac{1}{r_3}+\frac{1}{r_4}}.$$

Then, I reached the following conjecture (of course, this is just a conjecture) : 
$$r_0=\frac{n-1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{r_i}}.$$

I don't have any good idea for $n$ in general. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is an escribed sphere? You might want to define this in the question.

Comment: @IgorRivin: Thank you for pointing it out. I hope this is better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $S_1,\dots,S_{n+1}$ be the $(n-1)$-dimensional volumes of the corresponding faces, and $V$ be the $n$-dimensional volume of the simplex. Then $\displaystyle V=\frac{r_0S}n=\frac{r_i(S-2S_i)}n$, where $S=\sum_i S_i$. Thus 
$$
  \frac {n-1}{r_0}=\frac {(n-1)S}{nV}=\frac{\sum_i (S-2S_i)}{nV}
  =\sum_i\frac{1}{r_i},
$$
as required.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand why $\frac{r_0S}n=\frac{r_i(S-2S_i)}n$ ?

Comment: The relation $V=\frac{r_i(S-2S_i)}n$ is obtained in the same way as the area of a triangle is expressed via its exradius.